# Disconnecting from Firebase 3.x in Node

Tags: node.js, firebase

I have a short running micro-service in NodeJS which needs to connect to a Firebase DB, do a few things, and then disconnect. The current code uses the `firebase.goOffline()` method as there was nothing else that looked anything like it would provide a graceful exit/tear down.

Having now looked at the documentation though it feels like this API call is not really achieving what I'm after. What is the right way to return the resources to the database once you're done with them?

Comment: Why do you need to disconnect?

Comment: well at least historically not doing this created extra/unneeded resources building up on the server side and also there used to be a limit on the the number of concurrent active users and not cleaning up lead to this number to grow very quickly. Someone from their tech support suggested steps that worked in the 2.x product but don't seem to be represented in 3.